# How do I align these numbers on the decimal in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My activity fullscreen.xml has this excerpt which works exactly the way I want, producing output with the decimals aligned:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="-0.123"
            android:id="@+id/acc_x"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="0.123"
            android:id="@+id/acc_y"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="99.123"
            android:id="@+id/acc_z"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:text="99.123"
            android:id="@+id/acc_T"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

But when I calculate numbers and fill those same text boxes with this code, the alignment changes:

```
        x = -0.123f;
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_x);
        text.setText(String.format("%-8.3f",x));

        y = 0.123f;
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_y);
        text.setText(String.format("%-8.3f",y));

        z = 99.123f;
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_z);
        text.setText(String.format("%-8.3f",z));

        T = 0;
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_T);
        text.setText(String.format("%-8.3f",T));
```

[image]

**What can I do to keep the alignment on the decimal point as intended?**

Here is my build.gradle in case that matters:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app001"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: One thing, you don't need to specify exact sizes for your TextViews, you can simply use "wrap_content" for their layout_height and layout_width and use margins/padding for positioning.

Comment: Use a table layout with 3 columns having a text view each. Split your string into two by '.' and set the pre decimal part in the first column with gravity right, a '.' in the second column and the post-decimal part in the third column with gravity left. Nice colour selection btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in your layout.xml. I ran this piece of your code with a change to the string formatting and the problem was gone.

```
  x = -0.123f;
  text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_x);
  text.setText(String.format("%.3f",x));

  y = 0.123f;
  text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_y);
  text.setText(String.format("%.3f",y));

  z = 99.123f;
  text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_z);
  text.setText(String.format("%.3f",z));

  T = 0;
  text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_T);
  text.setText(String.format("%.3f",T));
```

Comment: This is probably the way for me to go. I'll try it later when I get a chance.

Comment: This did the trick and aligned them as I wanted, although it's not really clear to me why using the format I specified does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:gravity="right"` on your `TextView`s.

That will line up the right hand edge.

Then drop the `-8` space padding, not needed now:

```
text.setText(String.format("%.3f",y));
```

You may also need to use a fixed width font if you want the decimal point to line up.

Comment: layout_width should have a fixed dp.

Comment: @timmyt123 why and which layout width?

Comment: Hi, the TextView layout_width.  If the layout_width is wrap_content then gravity won't be able to move it.  I stated it for others because the originator has a fix width of 140 dp.

Comment: @timmyt123 ok, that's interesting, surprising even. Will check it out myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
x = -0.123f;
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_x);
text.setText(String.format("%-8.3f",x));
text.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large);

y = 0.123f;
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_y);
text.setText(String.format("%-8.3f",y));
text.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large

z = 99.123f;
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_z);
text.setText(String.format("%-8.3f",z));
text.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large

T = 0;
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_T);
text.setText(String.format("%-8.3f",T));
text.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large
```

Comment: I get build failures with "cannot find symbol variable context" and "cannot find symbol variable Base". I can sub 'this' for 'context', but I'm not sure what to do about 'Base'. (?)

Comment: It is the style you have defined in your xml. Try "android.R.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"

Comment: I can use this line of code: 'text.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);' but no diff

Comment: Try this in your xml. 
android:layout_gravity="right"

Comment: I tried 'right' before I tried 'end'. Both gave the same results.